# Rails get most recommended product

Tags: postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have:
`Product` => `has_many :reviews`
`Review` has a field `recommendation:boolean`

I need to retrieve the Product that has most `Review.recommendation:true`
What would be the optimal approach here?

The product must also be present in the given array of categories.
I am trying something like this:

```
Product.joins(:reviews).where('category_id IN (?)', categories_ids).where(reviews: {recommendation: true}).group(:id)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being my approach:

```
res = Product.joins(:reviews).where('category_id IN (?)', categories_ids).where(reviews: {recommendation: true}).group(:id).count
    result = res.sort_by {|k,v| v}
    id = result.last[0]
    Product.find(id)
```